# spring boot REST response gzip compression not working

Tags: spring-boot, compression, gzip

I'm trying to add gzip compression in spring boot REST project . I already 
set  the following property in  `application.properties`

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=2048
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/css,application/javascript,application/json
```

But it does not work. Response Headers in postman show

```
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

The data is still not compressed.

Comment: The `Content-Encoding` header suggests that the response is compressed. How have you determined that it isn’t compressed? Are you certain that Postman isn’t automatically decompressing the response before displaying it to you?

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can determine the actual gzip size ?

Comment: To determine actual gzip size, you'll have to sniff the packet on the network. You can try Wireshark for that. There's a good tutorial here: http://bisaga.com/blog/programming/web-compression-on-spring-boot-application/

Comment: I have the same exact settings, except with a `Content-Type: application/gzip` (my endpoints serve gzip files), and the files are not compressed.  They are simply in plaintext.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Content-Encoding: gzip Says it is compressed - Postman decompress body for you so you can actually see the content not some garbage.